# Access ClaimsIdentity within Login method

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, claims-based-identity

I am trying to confirm a user has a given claim before they are logged in to the system. With the following code, the first time I hit the Login submit button, the HasClaim property returns false, and login fails. The second time the button is clicked (even without closing and reopening the login form) HasClaim returns true. Is it possible to get the property the first time I try to login ?

```
try
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, rememberme, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {                   
                bool hasClaim = User.HasClaim("ComponentAccess", component);  (w......
```

Comment: Not via User property. User is only properly populated on the next request. Why do you even need it in the Login method? User isn't accessing anything during that request. He will always be redirected to another page/action in order to obtain some data or not. You can directly fetch them from Database though, but whats the point? Claims are pieces of information, often used to check access permissions. Not something you do during a login request

Comment: The system has multiple components, and only one can be logged in to at any given time from a dropdownlist on the login form. The user may have access to one or several of these components. I don't want a given user who does not have access to, say the accounting component, to be logged in if they choose accounting from the dropdownlist. My intention is that only the logged-in component will be visible on successful login.

Comment: Yes, but you don't have to do that during login. Add claims to your user, then log him in. On each request use the claims to see if they have access to it, if not return 403 (forbidden) or use the claim to show/hide the menus or whatever if you are in mvc

Comment: Thanks! Will do.